# Automation not working for my create project procedure

Tags: python, github

This is my code and the error message I am receiving.
Where am I going wrong?

```
import sys
import os
from github import Github

path = "/home/andycodes/"

def create():
    folder_name = str(sys.argv[1])
    os.makedirs(path+folder_name)
    username = "USERNAME"
    password ='PASSWORD'
    user = Github(username,password).get_user()
    repo = user.create_repo(folder_name)
    print(f"New Repository '{folder_name}' created successfully.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    create()
```

```
  File "/home/andycodes/Dev/automation/create_project/create.py", line 18, in <module>
    create()
  File "/home/andycodes/Dev/automation/create_project/create.py", line 14, in create
    repo = user.create_repo(folder_name)
  File "/home/andycodes/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/github/AuthenticatedUser.py", line 680, in create_repo
    headers, data = self._requester.requestJsonAndCheck(
  File "/home/andycodes/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/github/Requester.py", line 353, in requestJsonAndCheck
    return self.__check(
  File "/home/andycodes/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/github/Requester.py", line 378, in __check
    raise self.__createException(status, responseHeaders, output)
github.GithubException.GithubException: 401 {"message": "Requires authentication", "documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/rest/reference/repos#create-a-repository-for-the-authenticated-user"}
```

Comment: Something is wrong with your credentials.

Comment: I was thinking that too, but i double checked and it is right..

Comment: Have you checked the login information? A quick google search shows people with similar issues, and the documentation says that you must be signed in, or have access to the proper login information, otherwise you will receive this specific error. Try checking those one more time, and see if it works?

Comment: I checked it again now and my details are definitely right. Also i am logged in. I see there are a few people that have the same issue..

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you must generate token on [GitHub Tokens Page](https://github.com/settings/tokens)
Second of all, write this:

```
os.makedirs(os.path.join(path, folder_name))
token = 'ghp_pRwRBd46KZ3Uee6SUf10b4RLwOoyLS2xTPax' #it is made up
g = Github(token)
user = g.get_user()
repo = user.create_repo(folder_name)
```